# Calculate the vertical px value of the distance between 2 divs

Tags: jquery

I have a complex layout of DIVS sat within a parent wrapped DIV. Every 1st, 6th, 11th, 16th etc.. DIVs have an absolute position, the rest are relative positioned. I have an ajax function to load another 5 on a button click, this all works well... except - if there is just 1 div to display when clicking the ajax load more button - the last div gets place in the right position... but... of course as its absolute positioned - it's height is not respected by the wrapped div holding it and all the others...

I need to manually set the height of the wrapper div to fix this I think - so I was thinking of working out the difference between the top edge of 1st child in the wrapper and the bottom edge of the last in the wrapper before the ajax function to add another - I could then add the height of the newly added orphan div to this calculated value to set the height of the wrapper div... that's the theory... Would it work? Any chance of a code suggestion on how to achieve it? All my trials have failed so far...

Diagram helps illustrate what I am trying to do, so first 5 divs (black blocks) are in place (FIRST div is absolute positioned, rest are relative), orange bars show the height I want to calculate, the red NEW LAST DIV is the one added via Ajax load more - positioned absolute, so currently the wrapper does not include its height in its height.
[image]

ACTUALLY... setting the height of the wrapper div messes up the layout of the divs inside it... so.. thinking it might need to be an ugly solution by adding some bottom margin to the wrapper to allow it to visually encapsulate the red orphaned div....

Comment: Use CSS and something like flexbox for layout, not JavaScript. You're going to give yourself a headache with different screens, different resolutions etc

Comment: using margin-bottom worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

Setting margin-bottom on the wrapper div to the outerHeight of the last (new) div worked.